# Why this map preserves order?

Tags: natural-numbers, ordered-fields

How to prove that  $f:N→\{1,1+1,1+1+1,...\}$ where 1 is an identity element of ordered field, is order-preserving? I guess that maybe property 
if $a < b$ then $a + c < b + c$
can be useful, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: If $f$ maps $1$ to $1+1$ and everything else to $1$, then it isn't order preserving. Did you mean to tell us something about $f$, like perhaps $f(n)=1+1+1+...+1$ or that it's additive?

Answer (score 1):

Surely *some* condition needs to be put on $f$, since you can easily construct bad maps that disturb order.

A suitable condition would be for $f$ to be additive.

Suppose additivity: then $f(1)\in\{1,1+1,1+1+1\dots\}$ somewhere. Every other image is now already determined. For example, $f(2)=f(1)+f(1)>f(1)$, where the last inequality follows from the axiom you mentioned in your OP.

By induction, you can show $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(1)>f(n-1)$ holds for all $n$, showing it is order preserving overall.

---

In case you meant something even easier (the map $n\mapsto 1+1+\dots+1$ ($n$ times), then you can apply the same reasoning, because this map is additive. In this case it's more transparent that the sums of $1$ are an order-isomorphic copy of $\Bbb N^+$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, in your ordered field $F$, $1_F>0_F$, and monotonicity of sum in $F$ helps you to prove by induction your thesis.